# Getting error: [,data.frame [new.data, , object$method$center, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, knn, predict

I am receiving the error [,data.frame [new.data, , object$method$center, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected when I am attempting to normalize values for a kNN problem.

I imported the UniversalBank dataset, which has 5,000 observations and 14 variables. [image: UniversalBank data frame]

The below code is removing the ZIP code variable (5), creating dummies for the Education variable, and partitioning data into a 60/40 training and validation sets. A new customer is added, and the variables are normalized.

```
bank.df <- UniversalBank
# remove zip code
bank.df <- bank.df[,-5]

# create dummies for education
bank.df$Education <- as.factor(bank.df$Education)

library(fastDummies)
bank.dummies.df <- dummy_cols(bank.df, select_columns = c("Education"), 
                          remove_first_dummy = FALSE, remove_selected_columns = TRUE)

# partition the data into training (60%) and validation (40%) sets
set.seed(111)
train.index <- sample(row.names(bank.df), 0.6*dim(bank.df)[1])  
valid.index <- setdiff(row.names(bank.df), train.index)  
train.df <- bank.dummies.df[train.index, ]
valid.df <- bank.dummies.df[valid.index, ]
## new customer
new.df <- data.frame(Age = 40, Experience = 10, Income = 84, Family = 2, CCAvg = 2, 
                     Mortgage = 0, Securities.Account = 0, CD.Account = 0, Online = 1, 
                     CreditCard = 1, Education_1 = 0, Education_2 = 1, Education_3 = 0)

# initialize normalized training, validation data, complete data frames to originals
train.norm.df <- train.df
valid.norm.df <- valid.df
# use preProcess() from the caret package to normalize all predictors
# ignore ID (attribute 1) and response variable (attribute 8) 
library(caret)
norm.values <- preProcess(train.df[, -c(1,8)], method=c("center", "scale"))
train.norm.df[, -c(1,8)] <- predict(norm.values, train.df[, -c(1,8)])
valid.norm.df[, -c(1,8)] <- predict(norm.values, valid.df[, -c(1,8)])
```

Everything is fine until I enter the next line of code:

```
new.norm.df <- predict(norm.values, new.df)
```

**That's when I get this error:**

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , object$method$center, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Attached are the data frames I created, and below is the layout of the new.df data frame:
[image: Data objects]

Here is the layout for new.df

```
new.df
  Age Experience Income Family CCAvg Mortgage Securities.Account CD.Account Online CreditCard Education_1 Education_2 Education_3
1  40         10     84      2     2        0                  0          0      1          1           0           1           0
```

I'm at a loss as to why this error is occurring. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

RR

I tried removing ignore statements and nothing changed. I suspect new.df doesn't have the right number of columns, but I'm so new to R programming, I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: The problem is with the columns "SecuritiesAccount" and "CDAccount". They're named "Securities.Account" and "CD.Account" in `new.df`

Comment: @Mohanasundaram thank you for pointing that out! That didn't fix my error, unfortunately. I wonder, should I get rid of the "ID" column in the UniversalBank file? It doesn't exist in new.df.